# Reprojecting from WGS 1984 to Robinson 54030 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

The [shapefile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Dt45lRlqwLdjmFTi3lWw5Q5gAIdu-yeg?usp=share_link) is in WGS 1984 but I want to set the projection to 54030. When I'm doing that I'm getting a distorted display of the world map. I tried using the code `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=robin" name_fixed.shp name.shp` but that doesn't fix the error. Attaching a screenshot of the shapefile when the CRS is Robinson.

[image]